# Same value showing up as three values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column (Builder) in my database that I want to update the three values for and make it one single value since it is all the same but our data source treats it separately. I do not know what the dilemma is that even after the update statement, database still treats them as separate values. My data source shows a total of 5 rows and so does my database. What can I do to treat them as one, single value rather than three?

```
select * from traffic

Builder                      Contacts

Small Brother                   0
Big Brother                     8 
Brother                         10 
Neighbor                        7 
Friend                          5
```

I updated values in my table:

```
update traffic set Builder = 'Brothers' WHERE Builder in ('Brother',
     'Big Brother','Small Brother') ;
```

When I do

```
select distinct Builder from traffic

Builder

Brothers
Neighbor
Friend
```

It shows up as one value which is 'Brothers' meaning the update statement executed successfully.

Surprisingly, when I run

```
 select * from traffic

 Builder              Contacts

 Brothers              0
 Brothers              8
 Brothers              10
 Neighbor              7
 Friend                5
```

When I apply an aggregate function:

```
select Builder, sum(Contacts)
from traffic
group by Builder, Contacts

Builder                   Sum
Brothers                  8
Brothers                  10
Neighbor                  7 
Friend                    5
```

The result I need help with:

```
select * from traffic

Builder              Contacts

Brothers               18  
Neighbor               7
Friend                 5
```

Comment: `Group by Builder`, Not `Group by Builder, Contacts`

Comment: Check my answer. And check the @GurV comment

Comment: I was going to check off Will's answer but he deleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM traffic
```

Will give you every column and row in the traffic table.
Because you just updated 3 of the rows to say "Brother", you are getting back exactly that. In order to get back the result you want, you need to use a

```
GROUP BY
```

clause along with an aggregate clause.

Something like

```
SELECT Builder, SUM(Contacts) 
FROM traffic
GROUP BY Builder
```

This actually tells the database to first group by the builders, which will get rid of the duplicates, and then selects the count of all contacts. The SELECT statement is ran last in the database.

Comment: You don't need to group by contacts, it is already being aggregated by the SUM() function

Answer (score 1):

if you don´t want to update your data you can try with this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Builder LIKE '%Brother%' THEN 
        'Brother'
    ELSE 
        Builder
    END
    ,SUM(Contacts)
FROM traffic
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Builder LIKE '%Brother%' THEN 
        'Brother'
    ELSE 
        Builder
    END
```

Comment: @PLearner But have you tested this solution? And do not forget to just group by Builder

Comment: This solution is useful if you don´t want to update your data

Comment: @PLearner Thanks to you for appreciating the help